Error when runing mlflow with sklearn model
I'm training a RandomForestRegressor and keeping track of it using mlflow
Using the following code works perfectly only when n_estimators is lower than 90
The code:
import mlflow
import mlflow.sklearn
from mlflow.models import infer_signature
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, root_mean_squared_error

dataset = mlflow.data.from_pandas(
    final_result, source=file, name="SSM", targets="Shifted_10"
)

# Start the MLflow run
with mlflow.start_run(run_name='ssm_rain_predict_ssm'):
    # Initialize the Random Forest Regressor
    n_estimators = 100
    rf_regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators, random_state=42, verbose=True)
    mlflow.log_param("n_estimators", n_estimators)

    # Prepare target values
    y_train = y_train_df.values.ravel()
    y_test = y_test_df.values.ravel()

    # Fit the model
    rf_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Make predictions on the test set
    y_pred = rf_regressor.predict(X_test)
    signature = infer_signature(X_test, y_pred)

    # Calculate metrics
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    rmse = root_mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    print(f'Mean Squared Error: {mse}')
    print(f'Root Mean Squared Error: {rmse}')

    # Log metrics
    mlflow.log_metric("mse", mse)
    mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)

    # Prepare an example input from the training data, format if necessary
    input_example_no_fmt = get_train_data_point(df_cleaned, 2600, N)
    input_example = input_example_no_fmt.drop(input_example_no_fmt.columns[10], axis=1)

    mlflow.log_input(dataset, context="training")

    # Log the model with an input example
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=rf_regressor,
                                artifact_path="sklearn-model",
                                signature=signature,
                                registered_model_name="ssm_from_ssm_rain_type"
    )

When I run it, with lower values I get this log (I'm just hiding the url):
Registered model 'ssm_from_ssm_rain_type' already exists. Creating a new version of this model...
2024/10/29 14:55:23 INFO mlflow.store.model_registry.abstract_store: Waiting up to 300 seconds for model version to finish creation. Model name: ssm_from_ssm_rain_type, version 10
Created version '10' of model 'ssm_from_ssm_rain_type'.
2024/10/29 14:55:23 INFO mlflow.tracking._tracking_service.client:  View run ssm_rain_predict_ssm at: http://xxxxxxxxxxx:5000/#/experiments/62/runs/56abb7acc7c14d7a81e967a568a8bb74.
2024/10/29 14:55:23 INFO mlflow.tracking._tracking_service.client:  View experiment at: http://xxxxxxxxxx:5000/#/experiments/62.

However, when I increase n_estimators I get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResponseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
ResponseError: too many 500 error responses

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py:667, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    666 try:
--> 667     resp = conn.urlopen(
    668         method=request.method,
    669         url=url,
    670         body=request.body,
    671         headers=request.headers,
    672         redirect=False,
    673         assert_same_host=False,
    674         preload_content=False,
    675         decode_content=False,
    676         retries=self.max_retries,
    677         timeout=timeout,
    678         chunked=chunked,
    679     )
    681 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:944, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    943     log.debug("Retry: %s", url)
--> 944     return self.urlopen(
    945         method,
    946         url,
    947         body,
    948         headers,
    949         retries=retries,
    950         redirect=redirect,
    951         assert_same_host=assert_same_host,
    952         timeout=timeout,
    953         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    954         release_conn=release_conn,
    955         chunked=chunked,
    956         body_pos=body_pos,
    957         preload_content=preload_content,
    958         decode_content=decode_content,
    959         **response_kw,
    960     )
    962 return response

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:944, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    943     log.debug("Retry: %s", url)
--> 944     return self.urlopen(
    945         method,
    946         url,
    947         body,
    948         headers,
    949         retries=retries,
    950         redirect=redirect,
    951         assert_same_host=assert_same_host,
    952         timeout=timeout,
    953         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    954         release_conn=release_conn,
    955         chunked=chunked,
    956         body_pos=body_pos,
    957         preload_content=preload_content,
    958         decode_content=decode_content,
    959         **response_kw,
    960     )
    962 return response

    [... skipping similar frames: HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen at line 944 (2 times)]

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:944, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    943     log.debug("Retry: %s", url)
--> 944     return self.urlopen(
    945         method,
    946         url,
    947         body,
    948         headers,
    949         retries=retries,
    950         redirect=redirect,
    951         assert_same_host=assert_same_host,
    952         timeout=timeout,
    953         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    954         release_conn=release_conn,
    955         chunked=chunked,
    956         body_pos=body_pos,
    957         preload_content=preload_content,
    958         decode_content=decode_content,
    959         **response_kw,
    960     )
    962 return response

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:934, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    933 try:
--> 934     retries = retries.increment(method, url, response=response, _pool=self)
    935 except MaxRetryError:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:519, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    518     reason = error or ResponseError(cause)
--> 519     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    521 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/62/8c7575e5c786420d9ba78af9cc7f70cd/artifacts/sklearn-model/model.pkl (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RetryError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py:189, in http_request(host_creds, endpoint, method, max_retries, backoff_factor, backoff_jitter, extra_headers, retry_codes, timeout, raise_on_status, respect_retry_after_header, **kwargs)
    188 try:
--> 189     return _get_http_response_with_retries(
    190         method,
    191         url,
    192         max_retries,
    193         backoff_factor,
    194         backoff_jitter,
    195         retry_codes,
    196         raise_on_status,
    197         headers=headers,
    198         verify=host_creds.verify,
    199         timeout=timeout,
    200         respect_retry_after_header=respect_retry_after_header,
    201         **kwargs,
    202     )
    203 except requests.exceptions.Timeout as to:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/request_utils.py:237, in _get_http_response_with_retries(method, url, max_retries, backoff_factor, backoff_jitter, retry_codes, raise_on_status, allow_redirects, respect_retry_after_header, **kwargs)
    235 allow_redirects = env_value if allow_redirects is None else allow_redirects
--> 237 return session.request(method, url, allow_redirects=allow_redirects, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py:691, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    690 if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):
--> 691     raise RetryError(e, request=request)
    693 if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):

RetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/62/8c7575e5c786420d9ba78af9cc7f70cd/artifacts/sklearn-model/model.pkl (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MlflowException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[162], line 47
     44 mlflow.log_input(dataset, context="training")
     46 # Log the model with an input example
---> 47 mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=rf_regressor,
     48                             artifact_path="sklearn-model",
     49                             signature=signature,
     50                             registered_model_name="ssm_from_ssm_rain_type"
     51 )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/sklearn/__init__.py:413, in log_model(sk_model, artifact_path, conda_env, code_paths, serialization_format, registered_model_name, signature, input_example, await_registration_for, pip_requirements, extra_pip_requirements, pyfunc_predict_fn, metadata)
    334 @format_docstring(LOG_MODEL_PARAM_DOCS.format(package_name="scikit-learn"))
    335 def log_model(
    336     sk_model,
   (...)
    348     metadata=None,
    349 ):
    350     """
    351     Log a scikit-learn model as an MLflow artifact for the current run. Produces an MLflow Model
    352     containing the following flavors:
   (...)
    411 
    412     """
--> 413     return Model.log(
    414         artifact_path=artifact_path,
    415         flavor=mlflow.sklearn,
    416         sk_model=sk_model,
    417         conda_env=conda_env,
    418         code_paths=code_paths,
    419         serialization_format=serialization_format,
    420         registered_model_name=registered_model_name,
    421         signature=signature,
    422         input_example=input_example,
    423         await_registration_for=await_registration_for,
    424         pip_requirements=pip_requirements,
    425         extra_pip_requirements=extra_pip_requirements,
    426         pyfunc_predict_fn=pyfunc_predict_fn,
    427         metadata=metadata,
    428     )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/models/model.py:743, in Model.log(cls, artifact_path, flavor, registered_model_name, await_registration_for, metadata, run_id, resources, **kwargs)
    741     elif tracking_uri == "databricks" or get_uri_scheme(tracking_uri) == "databricks":
    742         _logger.warning(_LOG_MODEL_MISSING_SIGNATURE_WARNING)
--> 743 mlflow.tracking.fluent.log_artifacts(local_path, mlflow_model.artifact_path, run_id)
    745 # if the model_config kwarg is passed in, then log the model config as an params
    746 if model_config := kwargs.get("model_config"):

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py:1170, in log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path, run_id)
   1136 """
   1137 Log all the contents of a local directory as artifacts of the run. If no run is active,
   1138 this method will create a new active run.
   (...)
   1167             mlflow.log_artifacts(tmp_dir, artifact_path="states")
   1168 """
   1169 run_id = run_id or _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
-> 1170 MlflowClient().log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py:1977, in MlflowClient.log_artifacts(self, run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
   1930 def log_artifacts(
   1931     self, run_id: str, local_dir: str, artifact_path: Optional[str] = None
   1932 ) -> None:
   1933     """Write a directory of files to the remote ``artifact_uri``.
   1934 
   1935     Args:
   (...)
   1975 
   1976     """
-> 1977     self._tracking_client.log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py:874, in TrackingServiceClient.log_artifacts(self, run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
    865 def log_artifacts(self, run_id, local_dir, artifact_path=None):
    866     """Write a directory of files to the remote ``artifact_uri``.
    867 
    868     Args:
   (...)
    872 
    873     """
--> 874     self._get_artifact_repo(run_id).log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/http_artifact_repo.py:80, in HttpArtifactRepository.log_artifacts(self, local_dir, artifact_path)
     76     artifact_dir = (
     77         posixpath.join(artifact_path, rel_path) if artifact_path else rel_path
     78     )
     79 for f in filenames:
---> 80     self.log_artifact(os.path.join(root, f), artifact_dir)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/http_artifact_repo.py:63, in HttpArtifactRepository.log_artifact(self, local_file, artifact_path)
     61 extra_headers = {"Content-Type": mime_type}
     62 with open(local_file, "rb") as f:
---> 63     resp = http_request(
     64         self._host_creds, endpoint, "PUT", data=f, extra_headers=extra_headers
     65     )
     66     augmented_raise_for_status(resp)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py:212, in http_request(host_creds, endpoint, method, max_retries, backoff_factor, backoff_jitter, extra_headers, retry_codes, timeout, raise_on_status, respect_retry_after_header, **kwargs)
    210     raise InvalidUrlException(f"Invalid url: {url}") from iu
    211 except Exception as e:
--> 212     raise MlflowException(f"API request to {url} failed with exception {e}")

MlflowException: API request to http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net:5000/api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/62/8c7575e5c786420d9ba78af9cc7f70cd/artifacts/sklearn-model/model.pkl failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxxx.xxxx.Xxxxx', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/62/8c7575e5c786420d9ba78af9cc7f70cd/artifacts/sklearn-model/model.pkl (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))

Why am I getting this error? How could I fix it?
Thanks

Your code is not runnable. Please include the full traceback message.

@Anonymous I cannot share the train data, but i did add the full error
